# Enable/Disable Group Box with Radio Buttons?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Bear with me here, relatively new to C#.

There is a set of radio buttons outside a group box, and then two and a text box inside said group box.  By default, No is checked, Yes is not checked, and "If Yes" (groupBox3) is disabled (it does not appear so in design mode).

I would post an image, but do not yet have 10 reputation.

I'm trying to set it up where if Yes is checked, groupBox3 is enabled, and everything in it is able to be used, and if I select No again, it disables everything in it.

Naturally, the default function is:

```
   private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
```

I have also tried using a second CheckedChanged function for radioButton2 (Yes button), but to no avail as well.

Under either function, I have tried all of the following iterations, and none have set it up to toggle whether groupBox3 is enabled/disabled.

```
groupBox3.Enabled = !radioButton1.Checked //Disables gb if No is checked
groupBox3.Enabled = radioButton2.Checked //Enables cb if Yes is checked

if(radioButton1.Checked)
    {
        groupBox3.Enabled = false; //Disables if No
    }
else if(radioButton2.Checked)
    {
        groupBox3.Enabled = true; //Enables if Yes
    }
```

What am I missing?  Am I not using the right functions or logic?

EDIT:  So I somehow solved this problem on my own.  Regenerated the function and used

```
groupBox3.Enabled = radioButton2.Checked
```

and suddenly it works as intended.  I tried this before and it didn't work, but suddenly it does now.  Well, I guess that's a problem solved.

Comment: Use the debugger.  Put a debugger stop on your first line inside that method and watch what happens when you click your radio button.

Comment: So I'm not sure what happened, but I regenerated the radioButton1_CheckedChanged function and put "groupBox3.Enabled = radioButton2.Checked;" in it and suddenly it is working as intended.

I tried that before and it failed, but suddenly it works now.  Probably gonna get downvited to hell for solving my own problem without even knowing how all of a sudden.

Comment: `I regenerated the radioButton1_CheckedChanged function`  Sounds like your method wasn't wired up to the event.